# Custom workflow based on templates with multi-user e-sign

Tags: docusignapi

After initial browsing in Google, I couldn't work out the scope of DocuSign API.

I would like to know if it's feasible to implement these features

- Multiple templates with custom form fields
- Assign workflow to templates - **multi-user e-signing by stages?**

  - automate e-signing internally
- User management/privileges - to create new document, recall/cancel, etc
- Manage List of recipients - type association
- Reporting such as; number of documents signed in the last month,

Please briefly explain what is DocuSign capable of and what needs to be developed differently

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer to your question is "yes." The [DocuSign website](http://www.docusign.com), [Developer Center](http://docusign.com/developer-center), and [Signature API reference documentation](http://docs.docusign.com) can help you understand the DocuSign Signature product and APIs.

If you have additional questions, you can talk with DocuSign staff, or try it for yourself. The Developer center enables you to create a free developer sandbox.

For API issues, you can also ask questions here on StackOverflow. Note that your questions should be much more specific than the questions you listed above. You also should show what you have already tried and what is not working for you.